# EditorFor can't post MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've come across a peculiarity with EditorFor() helper in MVC 3.

I have a form view that is strongly type (trimmed down):

```
@model GoGoLegal.Models.Address

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)       
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    </div>  
<div>
     <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</div>
}
```

and I have an Address EditorTemplate.

When the Input Button is click without anything in the fields then Validation gets thrown, however when there are values in the fields and the Input Button is clicked then nothing happens.. at all... It doesn't hit the controller, both HttpWatch and FireBug don't even register the event. I'm wondering whats happen.

I've also tried to replace

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

with

```
@Html.EditorForModel(Model)
```

And still the same thing.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe problem with client side validation? Show code where you specify validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your cache.  Sometimes a cached version of the page gets confused.  Try Ctrl-F5 after you've loaded the page, then see if the page posts.

Also, look at your code and make sure there aren't any malformed tags.  That can also confuse the browser, maybe you don't close everything.

Also check the actual HTML in the browser with a "View source" and see if the HTML looks correct.